# Unable to install Ruby Gems 3.0.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, runtime-error, runtime, rvm

I am trying to re-install Ruby 1.9.3 on a Raspberry Pi via RVM due to a dependency error by Logstash and getting the below error. Anyone else had a similar issue:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p551 to /home/pi/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551.....
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /home/pi/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /home/pi/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/CVE-2015-1855-p484.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /home/pi/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/update-autoconf.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /home/pi/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/openssl3.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #configuring..............................................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #post-configuration..
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #compiling..........................................................................................................................................................................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #installing........................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #making binaries executable..
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #downloading rubygems-3.0.3
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #extracting rubygems-3.0.3......
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #removing old rubygems........
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #installing rubygems-3.0.3..
Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global GEM_PATH= /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -d /home/pi/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.3/setup.rb --no-document',
please read /home/pi/.rvm/log/1555769993_ruby-1.9.3-p551/rubygems.install.log
```

Error in log file:

```
command(7): env GEM_HOME=/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global GEM_PATH= /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -d /home/pi/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.3/setup.rb --no-document
Exception `LoadError' at /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1264 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1273 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
/home/pi/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': /home/pi/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL (SyntaxError)
    module_function define_method(:warn) {|*messages, uplevel: nil|
                                                              ^
/home/pi/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb:18: void value expression
/home/pi/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn.rb:43: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
        from /home/pi/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/pi/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.3/lib/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'
        from setup.rb:28:in `require'
        from setup.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Any suggestions? I am not really familiar with Ruby or RVM so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ruby 1.9.3-p551](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/releases/) was released in November 2014, it's possible that compatibility has been broken at this point with the latest rubygems.

Try installing older versions of [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update/versions), I would start with `2.4.4` because it aligns well with the release of Ruby 1.9.3 but I would also try upgrading to anything `2.X` cause one should expect support to last a few years.

The project's [changelog](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/edf1dbd5b1ecf0cc55e06f59fa1007b4f55ef612/History.txt#L293) does mention removal of compatibility code for 1.9.2.

Comment: Support for anything < Ruby 2.2 [was removed](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/2182) in Rubygems 3.0. Thus, the currently latest version of Rubygems still supporting Ruby 1.9.3 is Rubygems 2.7.9. In any case, it's probably a good idea to upgrade to a newer Ruby which then also receives security updates. Ruby 1.9.3 should be obsolete now.

Comment: I've the same problem on OSX Mojave. How I can specify to install ruby 1.9.3 by RVM downloading and installing an older version of rubygems? It's seems that RVM download, extract and install rubygems 3 automatically trying to delete every older version could be present

Answer (score 3):

Was running on same issue. You need to change the ruby gem version to 2.7.3 default its taking 3.0.8

- rvm_rubygems_version=2.7.3 rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was downgrading to an older version of rvm.

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s 1.28.0
```